# take path of script as an argument python

Tags: python

I have this python script which sits in

```
/some/folder/foo.py
```

So if I am in `/some/folder` and do

```
python foo.py
```

the script runs great. Now I want to take this path `/some/folder` as an argument, so that I can run this script when in different folder.

something like if I am in `/a/different/folder` and from this folder I want to execute

```
foo.py
```

How do i do this?
Thanks

Comment: I think this is really a shell question, since it would be the same for running python scripts, perl scripts, or any other program. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recommendation would be to do the opposite, accept a parameter to run the script in, if its not provided to current directory.

```
foo.py <path_to_run_script_on>
```

Then all you have to do is make sure foo.py is on your path.

```
import sys
import os
if __name__=="__main__":
 if len(sys.argv) > 1:
   p = sys.argv[1]
 else:
  p = os.path.abspath(os.path.curdir)

 print p
```

Comment: Can you elaborate.. I dont think I understood it completely 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just include the full path of the script :

```
python /some/folder/foo.py
```

If, inside your script, you have "relative" paths, just prepend `/some/folder` to each of the paths.

Comment: Hi.. This would work.. except.. the file sits on a server.. and on different servers this path maybe different :(

Comment: you can always get the host name of the box you are working on by using `hostname` .

Answer (score 1):

are you asking how to run this from the shell? You're looking for absolute paths:

```
/a/different/folder $ python /some/folder/foo.py
```

or relative paths:

```
/some/otherfolder $ python ../folder/foo.py
```

If you're looking to get the absolute path name of your script while running it:

```
import sys
import os.path

absolutePathToMe = os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

mypath = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

that will get you the path to the script that is currently being executed